# How to create a clip with Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm sorry if this question has already been answered, but I couldn't find anything that helped.

I'm new to Unity. I recently bought the book "Getting Started with Unity 5" from Packt, and followed it halfway through, but I'm stuck now.

It says:

> 1. In the Animation window, click on the up/down button to the right of the Idle_boy (Read-Only) text. This will bring up a list of
>      animations for the current character, as shown in the following
>      screenshot: 
>      [image from the book](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CwE8M.jpg)
> 2. At the bottom of the current pop-up dialog, select [Create New Clip]. This will bring up a Create New Animation dialog window.

Everything is fine, but when I click, my menu doesn't have the "Create New Clip" option, as shown on [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZdARl.jpg)

Has anyone ever had the same issue? Is there another way to create a clip from a different menu?
I'm using Unity 2017.1.0f3 Personal.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to achieve this by using another menu.

In the Assets list, I right clicked on a folder, then **Create > Animation**. I renamed the new animation and dragged & dropped it on my ThirdPersonController in the Hierarchy view. If anyone has the same problem, I hope this will help :)